# Where can I find a list of Rails error messages keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, validation

I'm trying to customize my error messages by modifying `en.yml`.

```
en:
  errors:
    messages:
      blank: "This is a required field."
```

And now, every empty field that has the `validates presence: true` validator shows this new message.

I want to find a list of messages *types* to modify. For example, how can I customize the `numericality` validator message? Or the `greater_than` validator?

Any suggestions where to find this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a list of the messages you can customize in the `en.yml` file:

```
validates_acceptance_of
`:accepted` (“must be accepted”)
validates_associated
`:invalid` (“is invalid”)
validates_confirmation_of
`:confirmation` (“doesn’t match confirmation”)
validates_exclusion_of
`:exclusion` (“is reserved”)
validates_format_of
`:invalid` (“is invalid”)
validates_inclusion_of
`:inclusion`(“is not included in the list”)
validates_length_of
`:too_short` (“is too short (minimum is {{count}} characters)”)
`:too_long` (“is too long (maximum is {{count}} characters)”)
validates_length_of (with :is option)
`:wrong_length` (“is the wrong length (should be {{count}} characters)”)
validates_numericality_of
`:not_a_number` (“is not a number”)
validates_numericality_of (with :odd option)
`:odd` (“must be odd”)
validates_numericality_of (with :even option)
`:even` (“must be even”)
validates_numericality_of (with :greater_than option)
`:greater_than` (“must be greater than {{count}}”)
validates_numericality_of (with :greater_than_or_equal_to option)
`:greater_than_or_equal_to` (“must be greater than or equal to {{count}}”)
validates_numericality_of (with :equal_to option)
`:equal_to` (“must be equal to {{count}}”)
validates_numericality_of (with :less_than option)
`:less_than` (“must be less than {{count}}”)
validates_numericality_of (with :less_than_or_equal_to option)
`:less_than_or_equal_to` (“must be less than or equal to {{count}}”)
validates_presence_of
`:blank` (“can’t be blank”)
validates_uniqueness_of
`:taken` (“has already been taken”)
```

Comment: "Any suggestions where to find this?"

Answer (score 8):

Further to Serg's answer, you can find the list of keys for built-in validators here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#error-message-interpolation

Answer (score 0):

It finds error message in a chain of namespaces. Consider a User model with a validation for the name attribute like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

The key for the error message in this case is :blank. Active Record will look up this key in the namespaces:

```
activerecord.errors.models.[model_name].attributes.[attribute_name]
activerecord.errors.models.[model_name]
activerecord.errors.messages
errors.attributes.[attribute_name]
errors.messages
```

Thus, in our example it will try the following keys in this order and return the first result:

```
activerecord.errors.models.user.attributes.name.blank
activerecord.errors.models.user.blank
activerecord.errors.messages.blank
errors.attributes.name.blank
errors.messages.blank
```

Hope it will help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To add on to @MikeL answer, which only shows the keys, the full list with the keys and interpolated messages can be found [here at rails very own github repository](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en.yml).